# Links to files are not clickable

Tags: html, pdf, puppeteer

I am using puppeteer for generating PDFs from HTML files. All of the normal links `https:\\` are clickable and are opening the browser, but also there is that need of files to be added as links and they are not clickable. Do you know why this may happen?

```
<div class="kc-link">
    <a href="file://W:\dir1\dir2\Washing.txt">Not clickable</a>
</div>
<div class="kc-link">
    <a href=https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bread>Clickable</a>
</div>
```

**EDIT:**
Those file links are just supposed to be opened in the users browser

Comment: May be the reason that if someone else use your pdf , at that point of time your file which is from local directory not found in that place.

Answer (score 0):

Add the pdf to the file structure of your project. For example, if it is in a file called "Docs" and your webpage is in the base folder of your project, you would use.

```
<a href="Docs\Washing.txt"></a>
```

Comment: Actually the pdf is generated online and it should just open the file location in the browser of the users.